# Inconsistency in the way android app treats election notifications

Tags: support, bug, moderator-election, android-app

Whenever someone comments on your election nomination, you get a notification in your inbox, like you would get for a regular post. These notifications show up just fine in the android app:

[image]

But when you try to access them, you get an error:

[image]

I understand the android app may not be the best place to handle elections (like, e.g., review queues are not available in the app), but could we at least have these notifications redirected to the browser, which can load the site, filtered out, or at least annotated somehow ("this comment is part of the moderator election page, please use the desktop version of to access it").